# Add Same Product Name with Quantity and Amount for Every Quarter in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom visual force page created on "Quote "Object in a PDF format where the data gets displayed .Writing Wrapper class i have achieved the data of opportunity forecast details.Now i would Like to get

1) To Add Same Product Name ,With Quantity and Amount for Every Quarter.

2)To Achieve the Subtotals and Grandtotals for the Quantity and Amount .

Any Suggestion Plz.Any help is very much appreicated.

PFA Screen Shot

For Example :Here the Product Name as "BXRC-25e4000-F-04" appears twice in a Quarter for the months Jan and Feb.Now the Quantity & Amount Should get Added displayed at one place and the product name should get appeared only once.
[image]

**Visual force Code :**

```
<h3>OpportunityForecast Details</h3>
 <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="3"  ></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" colspan="5" >FORECAST DATE</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>              
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Opportunity Name</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"></td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter 1 FY 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter 2 FY 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter 3 FY 2014 </td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter 4 FY 2014 </td>
                <!--<td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Amount</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Month</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Actual Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Year</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Date</td>--> 
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">MonthText</td> 
               <!-- <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastDate</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastName</td>-->
                <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Grand<br/>Total </td> 
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>

                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Opportunity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data" >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/><br/><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/><br/></td>
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quarter }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Actual_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Year }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_date }"/></td> --> 
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month_Text }"/></td> 
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Forecast_Date }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Name }"/></td>-->
                <td rowspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>



             </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
                   <tr class="foot">
                      <!--<td align="right" colspan="2" width="10%" class="header-table-heading">
                              Subtotal: 
                         </td>

                         <td align="right" colspan="2" width="100%" class="header-table-heading">
                              Grandtotal: 
                         </td>
                         <td align="right" width="12%" class="subtotal">
                           <apex:OutputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity__c}"/>
                       </td>-->
                         <tr>

                     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data">SubTotal :</td>
                     <td colspan="0" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-data"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     </tr>
                         <tr>

                       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left"  align="right" class="header-table-heading">GrandTotal</td>
                       <td colspan="0" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"  >Forecast Qty<br/>ForecastAmt<br/> </td>
                       <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                     <td colspan="1" style="text-align:left" align="right" class="header-table-heading"> {!subtotalofquantity }<br/>

                     {!subtotalofAmount }<br/></td>
                       </tr>

                   </tr>
               </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**APEX CODE :**

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}




       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

    }

        Public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

        Public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       subtotalofquantity = 0;

       subtotalofamount = 0;

     // Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list(){
    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    // list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

   //  list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                     // Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   //  list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c ]  ; 

     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

     list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id order by gmod__Month__c asc limit 4]; 

   // list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist=[ SELECT  id,gmod__product__r.name,gmod__Quantity__c,createdby.name , gmod__opportunity__r.name ,gmod__Amount__c,GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c) grpQty, GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) grpAmt ,COUNT(id) oppfc from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c), GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) ];

  // Executes in DC 
  // [SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,COUNT(id) cnt FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];
//Executes in DC
 //list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist =[SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c)gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE  gmod__date__c=THIS_FISCAL_YEAR GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofamount  += integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);

            //for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c op: opflist ){

                    //system.debug('Opp id++ '+Quote.Opportunity.id);
                    //if(qt.Quote.Opportunity.id == op.opportunity__r.id){

                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                              disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
                    //}         
       }
     }
   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would post your controller class as we could then provide code improvements specific to your question. In general, you could use the GROUP BY functionality and Aggregate functions to SUM across the quarters and your MonthTest column would be Q1 / Q2 / Q3 / Q4 such that Q1 would be Jan/Feb/March  or whatever months you group together for Q1.

Comment: @TC Sutton:I have updated with code.I tried with GROUP BY functionality.It  got executed in Developer console.Month Text column is a formula field which has all the months included.Any help is very much appreciated